# How to get row values when we run SQL query from Linux Shell script

Tags: sql-server, linux, shell, unix

My shellscript contains below code to retrieve rows from a table in SQL server.

```sql
OUTPUT=aa.out

DATE_STR=20220103

{$ISQL} -U{$SQL_UU} -P{$SQL_PP} -S{$SERVER_NAME} << !! > {$OUTPUT}

GO

USE {$DB_NAME}

SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(8), LOGIN_TIME,112)={$DATE_STR}

GO

!!
```

I'm getting output in aa.out as below

```
locale is en_US.UFT-8

locale charset is UFT-8

using default charset UFT-8

1>2>3>4>EMP_NAME

ALICE
BOB
(1 row affected)
1>
```

how to modify my query or shellscript to get output

```
ALICE

BOB
```

Comment: For `sqlcmd`, use `-o yourfile` to output a query to file, rather than using `>`

Comment: I tried using ISQL/tsql where -o is not working